# Editing a .txt file - Algorithm not working

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

I want to automatially edit .txt files with code. Everything containing victory_poins shall be removed and entered in another form after the "history={" statement. But in the end, it adds an additional history={. Why?

Code:

```
def überschreiben(filename,vp, capital):
data_out=open(filename,"r")
data_in=open(filename+"_output.txt","w")

vpsegment=False
for line in data_out:
    if "\thistory" in line:
        data_in.write(line+'\n\t\tvictory_points = { '+str(capital)+' '+str(vp)+' }\n')

    if "\t\tvictory_points" in line:
        vppivot=line
        vpsegment=True

    if vpsegment==True:
        if "}" in line:
            data_in.write("")
            vpsegment=False
        else:
            data_in.write("")
    else:
        data_in.write(line)
data_in.close()
data_out.close()
```

Input:

```
state={
id=1
name="STATE_1" # Corsica
manpower = 322900

state_category = town

history={
    owner = FRA
    victory_points = { 3838 1 }
    buildings = {
        infrastructure = 4
        industrial_complex = 1
        air_base = 1
        3838 = {
            naval_base = 3
        }
    }
    add_core_of = FRA
}

provinces={
    3838 9851 11804 
}
}
```

Output:

```
[...]

state_category = town

history={

    victory_points = { 00001 8 }
history={
    owner = FRA
    buildings = {
        infrastructure = 4
        industrial_complex = 1
        air_base = 1
        3838 = {
            naval_base = 3
        }
    }
    add_core_of = FRA
}

provinces={
    3838 9851 11804 
}
}
```

Where does the second history={ come from?

Comment: It only outputs one `history={` line for me.

Comment: `"\thistory"` is in the line so it wrtes the first history. Then `vpsegment==False` so you go to the else statement and write the line (which contains "`history{`")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at what happens when you read the line `history{` :

```
if "\thistory" in line:
    data_in.write(line+'\n\t\tvictory_points = { '+str(capital)+' '+str(vp)+' }\n')
```

The line contains "\thistory" so it writes the lines (it writes the first "history{") and other things

```
if "\t\tvictory_points" in line:
    vppivot=line
    vpsegment=True
```

Nothing happens because the line does not contain "\t\tvictory_points"

```
if vpsegment==True:
    if "}" in line:
        data_in.write("")
        vpsegment=False
    else:
        data_in.write("")
else:
    data_in.write(line)
```

`vpsegment==False` so it goes to the else statement and write the line which is `"\thistory{"`